# MediaElement causes audible clicks

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, mediaelement

I'm developing a game, a Windows Store App based on XAML (not DirectX). To play sound effects (WAV files), I use the `MediaElement`. For every sound effect there is one (or several) MediaElement(s) that I initialize like this:

```
StorageFolder folder = 
    await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync(FolderPath);
StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(FileName);
IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

_mediaElement = new MediaElement();
_parentPanel.Children.Add(_mediaElement);
_mediaElement.AutoPlay = false;
_mediaElement.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
```

...and play like this:

```
_mediaElement.Play();
```

This works, but sometimes there are annoying audible clicks, like [this](http://www.freesound.org/people/stijn/sounds/43689/).

The strange thing is how consistent the clicks are: Some files never cause a click, some almost always and if they do it's always at the same position (for one it's the very beginning, for another it's close to the end). The clicks are **not** in the WAV files. When I play them in Audacity, everything is fine.

What's going on, here? How do I remedy this?

Comment: Can you discover any pattern? Are there situations where you just initialize program and do _mediaElement.Play() and you hear click? Or do you have to play() few mediaElements before there is chance of this happening?

Comment: @Erti-ChrisEelmaa: I cannot discover a pattern like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using XAudio2, SharpDX or MonoGame for sounds. As you noticed MediaElements are not geared towards that.